# How to add butt to 3d model?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, subdivision-surface

I have a 3d model that I want to add a butt to. (I am not doing this for NSFW purposes). I have tried various techniques including the inflate tool and proportional editing, but the model appears blocky and out of shape. (subdivision doesn't fix this). What's the best way I can edit a model to add a butt.

Comment: Suggestion.  Show your work or some purely geometric facsimile of it.  Your vertex density will determine how much ... non [blocky and out of shape] you can achieve.  You might also state your goal such as I want the butt or protrusion to have this kind of appearance _______.  There are plenty of human forms that are probably in the public domain that you can use as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

the best way is sculpting at a low resolution with dyntopo or with multiresolution instead if you dont care pretty much of making a retopo after doing a dyntopo sculpt , because dyntopo is triangle based topology, but multiresoltion is quad based topology. 
thats my two cents...if you need more info tell me...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the area in question is an extrusion such as a finger, arm or leg.  Increase your vertex density wisely if that meets your goals. Extrusion allows some isolation of your vertex density.  A cube can be considered   an extrusion of a flat plane.  With more vertex density the cube can be shaped into sphere with standard Blender tools in a few seconds.  If you are willing to add more vertices anything can be rounded.